# 503 from server: Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

Tags: gradle, artifactory, jib

I'm trying to build a jib based container with gradle.

I'm getting a 503 error when it tries to GET an xml file from jfrog.org.

```
    + eval set -- '"-Xmx64m"' '"-Xms64m"' '"-Xdock:name=Gradle"' '"-Xdock:icon=/Users/username/VSCode/globality-karate-testing/media/gradle.icns"' '"-Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew"' -classpath '"/Users/username/VSCode/globality-karate-testing/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar"' org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain ''\''jibDockerBuild'\'' \
 '
++ set -- -Xmx64m -Xms64m -Xdock:name=Gradle -Xdock:icon=/Users/username/VSCode/globality-karate-testing/media/gradle.icns -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /Users/username/VSCode/globality-karate-testing/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain jibDockerBuild
+ exec /Users/username/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java -Xmx64m -Xms64m -Xdock:name=Gradle -Xdock:icon=/Users/username/VSCode/globality-karate-testing/media/gradle.icns -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /Users/username/VSCode/globality-karate-testing/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain jibDockerBuild

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'karate-base'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.+.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Failed to list versions for org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/gradle/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/maven-metadata.xml'. 
Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity
```

This appears to be a problem with the jfrog.org server.

It only seems to happen if this is the first time someone has built the project.
Another engineer was able to replicate my error, who had not built this prior.
An engineer who had built the project earlier does not have problems. Seems to be an initialization file.

Comment: Apparently, https://repo.jfrog.org has an issues. We are looking into it.

Comment: Can you see if it works with https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heard back from Jfrog support.

The repo `https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/` has been deprecated.

Replace it with: `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2`